# Ошибка билда под андроид

Tags: unity3d

При попытке сделать билд под андроид выскакивает следующее:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Artom\New Game\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <7105be432fb64891b07085914e6cd5c1>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как понять в чём проблема через логи?

Ищём в логе `FAILURE:`  (это наша ошибка), читаем его, понимаем что "Сборка не удалась с исключением"

Ищём в логе дальше `* What went wrong:` (это то что пошло не так), читаем его и понимаем что `Your project path contains non-ASCII characters.`, что прямо нам говорит о том что путь с проектом содержит не читаемые символы, может в пути есть символы кириллицы?

Comment: Да, я уже разобрался. Спасибо что сказал где читать))